# Compiling command line with libraries in Linux with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, jsoncpp

I'm Android developer and engineer in computer vision.

I'm making a project of computer vision with OpenCV on a Mac, with OS X 10.9.5 in Xcode and it's cross-platform, so what I'm doing is a command line to compile into linux and access to it (server).

The problem that I'm having is that the library `JSONCPP` isn't being recognized. I compile it with:

> g++ -I/home/ec2-user/project/opencv/include/249include/include/ 
>   -L/home/ec2-user/project/opencv/build/lib/ -L/home/ec2-user/project/lib/ -I/home/ec2-user/project/jsoncpp-master/include/ -g -o binary main.cpp facerecognition.cpp utils.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_flann -w -std=c++11

Which part of the output is:

> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2475: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2478: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2479: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2484: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::Value(int)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2484: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::append(Json::Value const&)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2484: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2486: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::Value(std::string const&)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2486: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::operator[](char const*)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2486: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::operator=(Json::Value)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2486: undefined
>   reference to  `Json::Value::~Value()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2487: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::Value const&)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2487: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::operator[](char const*)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2487: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::operator=(Json::Value)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2487: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2488: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::append(Json::Value const&)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2479: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2489: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2491: undefined
>   reference to `Json::StyledWriter::StyledWriter()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2492: undefined
>   reference to `Json::StyledWriter::write(Json::Value const&)'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2475: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2484: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2486: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2487: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'
>
> /home/ec2-user/project/utils.cpp:2479: undefined
>   reference to `Json::Value::~Value()'

I have to mention that I have compiled this for Android (NDK) before with a this Makefile:

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
>
> OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
>
> include $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsoncpp/Android.mk
>
> include
>   /Users/rafaelruizmunoz/Desktop/AndroidDevelopment/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
>
> OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/rafaelruizmunoz/OpenCVtry/
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=
>   /Users/rafaelruizmunoz/Desktop/RD/OpenCVtry/Libraries/jsoncpp-master/include
>
> LOCAL_PATH := jni
>
> LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
>
> LOCAL_MODULE    := libXYZ
>
> LOCAL_MODULE_NAME    := mylibXYZ
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := facerecognition.cpp androidClass.cpp main.cpp
>   utils.cpp helper.cpp lbp.cpp
>
> LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl
>
> LOCAL_CPPFLAGS    := -std=c++11
>
> LOCAL_CFLAGS := -w
>
> CFLAGS=-w -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -Wno-write-strings
>   ../../include/boost
>
> LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libJsoncpp libopencv_java
>
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

which worked perfectly.

On my Mac it compiles perfectly. What I had to do is the JSONCPP Makefile with Xcode generator and adding as a project:

[image]

But I'm getting out of clues for compiling it into Linux.

Would you know what to do?
Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: You're getting errors compiling `utils.cpp` which feels more like you're either missing an `#include` line for the JSON stuff, or (depending what messages you've omitted) it's not finding the included file.  It doesn't look like you've got to link/library problems yet.

Comment: Hi @TripeHound thank you for your reply. I added a new include: `-I/home/ec2-user/project/json/` .... got other errors. Solved them but after that I get the same errors that I've mentioned.... :\

Comment: Can't do much more than repeat the earlier questions: does your `utils.cpp` have appropriate `#include` line(s) and are there earlier errors about not finding any include files?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess based on your Android makefile, since I can't see the included "BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES", but I noticed you've got:

"LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libJsoncpp libopencv_java"

I imagine you would need "-lJsoncpp -lopencv_java" on your g++ command line.

You have to be sure both libraries have been built and can be found in one of the "-L" paths